# Onsubmit anchor linking

Tags: php, html, css

When my contact form is not sent because of blank fields it reloads the site and shows an error message before the form. A "success" message is shown when everything is ok.
The problem is that the contact form is in the footer and you can't see either message without scrolling down yourself after sending the form.

I've tried this in the submit button, though it doesn't work.

```
<input type="submit" value="Send" onsubmit="location.href='#footer';">
```

Footer is the id where I want the user to be sent after submitting.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT

Using "index.php?#footer" instead of the id alone seems to work in the case of the error message, not in the case of success for some reason....

Comment: Since you're reloading the page, Javascript from the previous page doesn't have any effect. You need to use a redirect to `#footer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `#footer` to the form's `action` value

```
<form action="/some_path/#footer">
  <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to get the position of your element first.
Call it the following:

`<input type="submit" value="Send" onsubmit="anchorfunction('#footer');">`

Then your JS function should look like this:

`function anchorfunction(elem) {
    var top = document.getElementById(elem).offsetTop;
    window.scrollTo(0, top);
}`

This way you will get the top of your element and scroll within the current window to it.